# Add New Item To Grid

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I am trying to import music files from your pc to make your own playlist.
code below:

```
    public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Pick directory
    {
     var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
     openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
     openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
     openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
     openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
     var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
     var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

     // media is a MediaElement defined in XAML 
     if (null != file)
        {
          media.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
          media.Play();
        }
    }
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Import file
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(importedfile));
        importedfile import = new importedfile(); // The imported file goes to that page.  
        //What do I do to get the imported file into a new grid (Picture below
    }
```

For example: I Import a song and I hit the import button it will  navigate me to the importedfile page but what do I do next?.
[image]

Comment: can you clarify the problem you are having?

Comment: @Sayse  its not really a problem I just want to know how to modify a JSON file. sorry I didn't make it clear enough. (Programmatically)

Comment: What I do to modify JSON is to read the json file, deserialize the JSON into a `List<MyObjects>`, remove the `MyObject` from that list and then serialize the `List<MyObjects>` back to JSON and write it to the JSON file. To add, do the same but add a `MyObject` to the `List<MyObject>`. I can post a more detailed answer to that problem if that was your intended question. I use `Newtonsoft.Json` to work with Serializing and Deserializing. http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: @AndrewGrinder wow andrew you answered all of my questions :)